# I am trying to add to a dictionary in python using .update()

Tags: python, indexing, cs50, finance

I create a dictionary, ss, which has a total number of shares for a specific stock.  Then I need to do some calculations and create a new dictionary, temp, which I will feed into my .html page for presentation.  The update function does not work as I intend because all that is in temp is the last stock, not a listing of all the stocks I have purchased. When I print ss, there is [{key:value, etc}], but when I print temp there is no [  ] around the {key:value, etc}.  I think I am missing something basic.

Also my .html page is not reading the temp dictionary as the page is empty. Here is the code:

```
@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    """Show portfolio of stocks"""
    #dictionary to feed data into index
    temp={}
    #Select from trades all stocks held by this user
    ss = db.execute("SELECT SUM(shares), symbol FROM trades WHERE id=? GROUP BY symbol", session["user_id"])
    print(ss)
    #lookup current price for each stock and create index of all stocks held
    for row in ss:
        data=lookup(row["symbol"])
        totval=row["SUM(shares)"]*data["price"]
        temp1={"symbol":data["symbol"], "name":data["name"], "shares":row["SUM(shares)"], "price":data["price"], "total value":totval}
        temp.update(temp1)
        
    print(temp)
    return render_template("index.html", temp=temp)
```

Any direction would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: As per the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update), `update` "overite[s] existing keys"

Comment: Thanks.  Then how do I add another row to a dict?  My goal is to have an individual row for each stock containing: symbol, name, shares held and, total cost.  My current loop logic is only giving me the last row and I can not figure out how to "add" a row for each stock as I loop through the dict ss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR

```
# Note use of the data["symbol"]
temp.update({
    data["symbol"]: {
        "symbol": data["symbol"],
        "name": data["name"],
        "shares": row["SUM(shares)"],
        "price": data["price"],
        "total value": totval
    }
})
```

There are two generic manners of referencing related data, lists and dictionaries. In the simplest manner, consider:

```
apple
orange
pear
```

Using basic grammatical syntax, we can understand one is a list that "enumerates" it's part; the adjacency is the meaningful relationship between each individual part. The context and use of the list relates to it's external (variable) context.

A dictionary, on the other hand, specifies something specific is contextual to the *list* of *definitions* specifically. Consider:

```
fruit: apple, orange, pear
```

Here, fruit is an enumeration of different types of fruit; to define "fruit" is to give a list of qualifying "fruit" names contextual to an external (variable) context. Or:

```
fruit: An edible, usually sweet and fleshy form of such a structure.
```

Maybe a "real" definition.

So if we consider how we would refer to a list versus a dictionary, to add definitions to a list, we create a new list by (generally) appending a new item:

```
apple
orange
pear
+ kiwi
```

Before we had three, now we have four (contextually).

Whereas we append a new definition by specifying it's definition and naming it:

```
fruit: An edible, usually sweet and fleshy form of such a structure.
+ vegetable: A plant cultivated for its edible parts.
```

We could, if we want, update `fruit` by redefining it:

```
fruit: An edible, usually sweet and fleshy form of such a structure.
vegetable: A plant cultivated for its edible parts.
+ fruit: I like fruit.
```

Which gives us a dictionary of only it's constituent parts:

```
vegetable: A plant cultivated for its edible parts.
fruit: I like fruit.
```

Because you can only define (and update) the internal reference (`fruit`).

In psuedocode, a list:

```
fruits = []

fruits.add('apple')
fruits.add('orange')
fruits.add('pear')

// ['apple','orange','pear']
```

Likewise, a definition list works on the "key" relationship, and thus you may add or redefine a *key* relation:

```
foods = {}

foods['fruit'] = 'I like fruit.'
foods['vegetables'] = 'Gotta eat your veggies.'

// {
//    fruit: 'I like fruit.',
//    vegetables: 'Gotta eat your veggies!',
// }
```

In this sense, "updating" a dictionary means redefining and/or providing a new "key" relationship (internally).

Consider:

```
fruits = []

fruits.append('apple')
fruits.append('orange')
fruits.append('pear')

print(', '.join(fruits))

# apple, orange, pear

foods = {
    'fruits': 'Fruits are good.'
}

# Adding a definition
foods['vegetables'] = 'Gotta eat your veggies!'

# Updating a definition
foods.update({
    'fruits': 'I like fruit!',
    'meats': 'Can haz meat?'
})

for food in foods.values():
    print(food)

# I like fruit!
# Gotta eat your veggies!
# Can haz meat?
```

https://onlinegdb.com/SkneEJsw_

What you really need, then, are *unique* keys for your dictionary. Unique in the sense that within the dictionary's context, one key equals one definition. Which I think will look this:

```
# Note use of the data["symbol"]
temp.update({
    data["symbol"]: {
        "symbol": data["symbol"],
        "name": data["name"],
        "shares": row["SUM(shares)"],
        "price": data["price"],
        "total value": totval
    }
})
```

Or directly:

```
temp[data["symbol"]] = {
    "symbol": data["symbol"],
    "name": data["name"],
    "shares": row["SUM(shares)"],
    "price": data["price"],
    "total value": totval
}
```

Now you're updating your dictionary with meaningfully defined *terms* that resolve to a specific *definition* based on a *key* term.

Comment: This is by far the best answer I have ever gotten.  Thank you for your detail.  It helped me find my real problem which is I'm not rendering my dict properly into the html template.

Answer (score 0):

There already is an individual row for each stock in `ss`. Remember, key/value pairs can be added to dictionaries quite simply by "declaring" them, eg `row["totval"] = {value}`. Hint, SELECT as much as possible in the SQL, eg symbol, name in the sql.

Answer (score 0):

> When I print `ss`, there is `[{key:value, etc}]`, but when I print `temp` there is no `[]` around the `{key:value, etc}`. I think I am missing something basic.

I think you're mismatching types, which is a common mistake. I'm not sure what API/package you're using for `db.execute`, but that method seems to assign a `list` (`[]`) to `ss`. On the other hand, your `temp` value is a `dict`, (`{}`). I suggest one of two solutions.

If `render_template` expects `temp` to be a `dict` instead of a `list`, try this, as [DinoCoderSaurus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5577076/dinocodersaurus) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67346159/278156):

```py
def index():
    # other code here
    for row in ss:
        data = lookup(row["symbol"])
        totval = row["SUM(shares)"] * data["price"]

        # notice omission of data["symbol"] in temp1 assignment
        temp1 = { "name": data["name"], "shares": row["SUM(shares)"], "price": data["price"], "total value":totval }

        # assign temp1 to data["symbol"] key in new dict
        temp[data["symbol"]] = temp1
```

On the other hand, if `render_template` expects `temp` to be a `list` like `ss` seems to be, try:

```py
def index():
    # list to feed data into index (note change in data structure)
    temp = []

    # other code
    for row in ss:
        data = lookup(row["symbol"])
        totval = row["SUM(shares)"] * data["price"]
        temp1 = { "symbol": data["symbol"], "name": data["name"], "shares": row["SUM(shares)"], "price": data["price"], "total value": totval }
        temp.append(temp1)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't realize ss was a list until you pointed it out.  My issue is rendering the dict properly which isn't happending.